# elasticsearch подключить 2 ноды для сбора логов

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Подскажите, как правильно подключить 2 сервера с filebeat, которые отправляют данные в logstash, а тот уже в свою очередь в elasticsearch.

Я установил на серверах filebeat. В конфиге указал пути, с которых собирать логи, указал куда отправлять(output logstash). В самом Elаstike вижу, что индексы создались и данные наполняются. Но дело в том, что в индексы попадают данные с другого сервера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам, если кому интересно.

В настройках filebeat(filebeat.yml) нужно добавить какое-нибудь поля, которое будет описывать точку сбора логов этого сервера. Например,

```
fields: 
  log_type: log_85
```

Затем в настройках Logstash сделаем фильтр в конфигурации output. По этому полю нужные логи будут попадать в правильный индекс. Привожу пример:

```
output {
  if[fields][log_type]=="log_85"{
    elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    manage_template => false
    index => "85index"
    }
  }else{
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      manage_template => false
      index => "87index"
    }  
  }
}
```